# params hash not available to controller method but is visible in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's navbar search box in a Rails 4 app.  My form looks like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/search" method="get" role="search">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="know what you want?" name="q">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">find it!</button>
</form>
```

My controller method:

```
def search
  @temp = params[:q]
end
```

My view:

```
<%= @temp %>
```

My route:

```
match '/search',      to: 'dynamic_pages#search',       via: 'get'
```

When I fill in the textbox and click submit, the url changes and I can see the query string like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?q=blah
```

The trouble is, @temp is an empty variable when it comes time to display it in the view.

When I do this in the view:

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

I get the param hash.

I'll be grateful for any help I can get.

EDIT: Output from the console

```
Started GET "/search?q=blah" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-25 08:43:43 -0700
Processing by DynamicPagesController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"q"=>"blah"}
  Rendered dynamic_pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 21.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Could you show us the output from the console?

Comment: Can you post the params hash?

Comment: I've edited my question to show output from the console.  For some reason <%= params.inspect %> isn't working any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this, I solved the problem by moving the search action so that it was the first method in the dynamic_pages controller.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could suggest is that perhaps the `param` *is* available in the controller; maybe `@temp` is a reserved variable name or something?

I would immediately try the following:

> 1. In the controller, send the variable to the Rails console (to test its existence)
> 2. Try calling `@temp` something else

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/controllers/dynamic_pages_controller.rb
Class DynamicPagesController < ApplicationController
   def search 
      Rails.logger.info(params.inspect())
      @query = params[:q]
   end
end
```

This should output the params you have in your controller in the Rails log - whilst providing you with a different variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 you must permit your params.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

And btw you should change your route syntax to:

```
get "search" => "dynamic_pages#search"
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a strong parameters issue if he calls the parameter directly.